# Splitting line into strings based on whitespace without apache library

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, stream

I would like to split a line from a buffered reader into an array of strings based on the whitespace between them.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line;
```

I am aware of a method from an apache library that allow you to do so using

```
String[] words = StringUtils.split(line);
```

This is practice for a test and I won't have access to any external library's. How can I perform this operation exclusively using the JDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do:

```
String words[] = line.split(" ");
```

Notice the space within split call. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. This is perfect. I have no idea why I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Use split method of String class:
line.split("\s+")
All whitespaces will be considered as delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Built-in Java String class can do this. Read the documentation here:

[String Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Scroll down to the "split(...)" method.